# Redoing input if senses a string value instead of interger

Tags: string, python-3.x

My program breaks if a person inputs a letter instead of a interger the base of the problem is around here

```
        while quesses<6 :
            guesses = guesses+1
            guess = input("Guess a number 1 to 100)

            if int(guess) ==r:
               print("correct you took" + str(guesses) + "tries")
               break
```

the problem is if a letter is used it breaks what could I do to make it evaluate that it is a string the redo then input without increasing the value of guesses

Comment: ... Delay incrementing until you know you have valid input?

Comment: In python-2.x there is this method called `isdigit()` which returns true if the string object given is a number. So for example `'100'.isdigit()` is true. So if you converted `guess` to a string and then tested it for being a digit, you'd have the desired result: `if str(guess).isdigit() : ...` . That is of course assuming that isdigit() is also available in python-3.x (and i think it is)

Comment: @Alan this project is made using python 3.X not 2.x but ill see if that will work

Comment: @ Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams that helps with making it not take an extra guess, but still breaks when you enter a letter.

Answer (score 0):

Use some function to do the number parsing.

Parse the user input inside some `try`-`except` block.

If that succeeded `=>` increase counter and return result and counter.

If not `=>` call your number parsing function again.

Some simple number guessing game would be:

```
from random import choice


def get_number(current):
    result = None
    try:
        result = int(
            input('>>> [Round #{}] Guess a number between 1 and 100: '.format(
                current + 1
            ))
        )
    except ValueError:
        print('!!> [ERROR] Please try again')

    if result is not None:
        current += 1
        return result, current

    return get_number(current=current)


guesses = 0
unknown = choice(range(0, 100+1))
# print('>>> [debug] unknown is:', unknown)


while guesses < 6:
    guess, guesses = get_number(guesses)
    if guess == unknown:
        print('>>> you win!', 'took', guesses, 'guesses')
        break

print('>>> game over')
```